# Movie where a mom sees her daughter on the stairs, but then realizes that she has just drowned in the lake behind their house

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I'm trying to find the name of a movie I watched as a kid. I think it's either a late 80's or early 90's movie. It was like a ghost story or haunted house type movie.

There is one scene in particular that has stuck with me for years and I'd like to go back and watch the movie again if I can find it to see if this scene is still as creepy as I remember it being.

In the scene the mom is walking down stairs after being upstairs tidying up or something. As she comes down the stairs she is passed by her teenage daughter that is silently walking up the stairs. The mom realizes that the stairs are all wet and looks at the daughter.

The daughter is pale looking and soaking wet, the mom says something like "Honey what's the matter, you're dripping wet?!" Then the daughter turns and looks at her, but just then the husband is heard yelling from outside.

The mom turns and looks out the window and sees the father and some other people pulling the daughter, who appears dead out of the lake. The mom gasps and turns back to the stairs, but the version of her daughter she had been talking to has vanished.

Comment: Made me think of this scene from 'Don't Look Now', although it is a bit different. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8yqq6uBrKc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The movie is [Amityville 3-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amityville_3-D). Have very creepy scene. The drowned actress is Lori Loughlin:

[image]

> A reporter moves into the ominous Long Island house to debunk it of the recent supernatural events and becomes besieged by the evil manifestations which are connected to a hell-spawn demon lurking in the basement. - [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085159/)

Comment: It's better if you elaborate it a bit.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Just for future reference, if this is the correct movie, why would it need more elaboration ? Would Darren have to copy paste a description of the movie in his anwser ?

Comment: @Alexandre Details are required to show how this one is the correct one and not a wild guess. Details like how did this film matches with description given in question etc. Synonyms , trailer, specific scene  sometime helps too

Comment: I'm Darren. Not sure how to post images. I know this movie very well. It matches perfectly with the description. It shouldnt be hsrd to varyify. Its a famous scene. The father is sn actor whose name i dont know but was in the movie popcorn. I know horror films. Especially ones i own.

Comment: Meg Ryan is in it. Its famous.

Comment: Meg Ryan's in it. YOUTUBE - filmes de terror amityville 3 o demonio dublagem classica. Scene starts at the 104.08 mark

Comment: Wikipedia plot description-3rd paragraph

Comment: Freakin' awesome! Thanks Darren, From the Wiki, I feel confident this is the correct movie. I found it at the Netflix DVD site and have bumped it to the top of my queue. I'll watch it soon, but I do feel confident from the descriptions I've found online that this is the movie. Thanks a bunch!